# how do I change the label for each object in SerializeJSON

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to use ColdFusion's SerializeJSON() to return JSON data.

So far I have done this:

```
<cfset rows = [] />
<cfloop query="rsProducts">

    <!--- Create a row struct. --->
    <cfset row = {} />

    <!--- Add each column to our struct. --->
    <cfloop
    index="column"
    list="#rsProducts.columnList#"
    delimiters=",">
        <cfset row[ column ] = rsProducts[ column ][ rsProducts.currentRow ] />
    </cfloop>

    <!--- Append the row struct to the row array. --->
    <cfset arrayAppend( rows, row ) />
</cfloop>

<cfreturn SerializeJSON(rows, true)>
```

This works fine and produces JSON like this:

```
[Object {PRICE: 89.99, PRODUCTSTATUS: 1, COUNTRY: US}, Object {PRICE: 110.50, PRODUCTSTATUS: 4, COUNTRY: UK}, Object {PRICE: 41.20, PRODUCTSTATUS: 1, COUNTRY: IN}]
```

However instead of a label of "Object" for each item, I'd like it to be "ProductItem" instead. It just makes it easier for me to deal with in jQuery later on.

How could I have it so it labels each object in JSON as "ProductItem"?

Comment: That's not a label, that's it's type, and thats not valid json. The cfml code you have posted would not produce that output.  you might see that in your browsers dev tools, but that is not the raw json.

Comment: oh right, I didn't know that. Yes its what I saw in the Firebug console as the return from the server. I was trying to loop over the JSON using `$.each(ProductItem, function(k, v) { //do something here } );` hence I wanted each each item to be a ProductItem. I guess I will just have to use `this` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over the data in this manner easily.

```
.success(function(data) {
    var ProductItem  = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(ProductItem,function(key,value){
      console.log(value.PRICE +" "+ value.PRODUCTSTATUS + " " + value.COUNTRY);
    });
```

Comment: so rather than calling it `var a` I could call it `var ProductItem` and get the semantic meaning I was looking for.